# Adding name attribute to filter in magento

Tags: magento

Is there any way to display `name` attribute in Magento layered navigation for filtering products by name.
i need to list some products in the filter and give ability to a multiselection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price in the Layered Navigation.

I'm not sure why you would need Name in there, but a possible way to get it would be to create a product attribute dropdown called something like ln_name, set Use In Layered Navigation then assign it to the attribute set.  You would then have to populate ln_name with all of the product names in your catalog and go to each product and select the product's name from the list and save.  On the front end you would then have the product name as a layered nav option.

**To answer your second question below:**

Add a "Yes/No" attribute called "left_nav" and add it to your attribute set.  Go to your product listings and set "left_nav" to "Yes" for any that you want to be included in the collection.  Use this code in your template to call the products.  Note:  I haven't tested this but it should work.

```
$product_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('left_nav', array('eq' => 1))
                      ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                      ->load();
foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
    echo '<a href="'.$product->getProductUrl().'">'.$product->getName().'</a>';
}
```

Comment: i want to try adding manually list of products on the leftnav but do you know a method that i can select multiple product to display in the content, is it good way to resolve my problem?

Comment: See the edit above for the answer to your 2nd question.  hth!

Comment: yes, it's the first step but i need to add ability to multiselect using checkbox behind each product, than display the list in the main content. Is this possible

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are referring to when you say "add ability to multiselect using checkbox behind each product"?